# Service recovery not triggered on “A timeout was reached” error for a .NET service?

Tags: .net-framework, windows-services, timeout

A C# service that I have authored will occasionally not automatically start on VMs that are booting up -- we see the "A timeout was reached while waiting for the service to connect" entry in the Event Log.

The underlying issue is the same as what is described in [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986292/a-timeout-was-reached-while-waiting-for-the-service-to-connect-error-after-reb) -- but the difference here is that I have Recovery options set on the service to Restart the service on all failures.  This recovery process is not being triggered, however -- when this happens, the service must still be started manually after bootup is complete.

**Does the Recovery option only get triggered on a hard service crash, and not on a startup timeout?**

I use log4net and see zero log entries when this happens, so I'm not confident that any of my authored code is being executed before the timeout is hit (therefore solutions to use  [ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) or [WINAPI's SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686241.aspx) would have no effect).

Assuming this is some underlying issue with the .NET framework or similar being very slow to start (i.e. physical system resource or I/O contention as many VMs start up simultaneously), **will I need to author a lightweight C++ watchdog-type service to detect this issue and try to restart the service after the fact?**

---

More details:  This service was on a VM that rebooted twice to install Windows updates.  The service started up fine after the first reboot -- based on log statements, there was ~1 sec between the service constructor running and the beginning of the OnStart handler, and the service finished starting up within 2 more seconds.  On the second reboot, there were no log entries at all, just the Event Log "A timeout was reached" error, and upon inspection the service was not running.  A separate but similar .NET service that started up successfully after both reboots did take much longer the second time, though -- again based on log statements, ~0.7 sec after the first reboot, and 6 seconds after the second.

([asked originally on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420628/service-recovery-not-triggered-on-a-timeout-was-reached-error-for-a-net-servi), was recommended I ask here)

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue here and it seems you are correct, the Recovery option does not trigger on a startup timeout, only when a service actually crashes (although can't find any official documentation on this, it does seem to be a universal issue based on other reports).

A number of suggested ways to resolve this:

1. (Most recommended) Set the service 'Startup type' to 'Automatic (Delayed Start)' - this may help avoid the timeout by making the system wait for other critical system services to start before starting the service.
2. Make the troublesome service 'depend' on another service before it starts up (e.g. if the service is hanging due to a SQL server not being available) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config - e.g.

   sc config [firstservicename] depend=[secondservicename]
3. Create a scheduled task which attempts to restart the service if it has failed.
4. (Least recommended) Change the ServicesPipeTimeout setting for the Windows Service Manager to force Windows to wait longer when a slow service is starting up - will need to be updated on every machine the service is used on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/service-not-start-events-7000-7011-time-out-error

Hope this helps, it's an annoying issue, but can be resolved.